# Click Once deployment for Windows 8

Tags: wpf, clickonce, signing

I have a WPF click once application published to server with signing. It works perfectly and identified the publisher in client machine without problem. But in Windows 8, even though it works perfectly, it shows the smart screen filter at the end of download process. In which it displays that the publisher is not verified.

I have tried sign the EXE manually. But no luck.

A report for same bug seems to be closed by MS guys. Is this really fixed?

I am using Windows 8 RTM Enterprise.

Comment: Same here.
According to also this [forum post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winformssetup/thread/958afebb-4095-453f-ba3f-3b2d8aaedd24) RTM should have approached and solved the issue but it does not seem the case.